# Sequelize - include nested property/relation with a string name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following structure:

```
export class ResearchRequestEntity{

    @ForeignKey(() => ResearchEntity)
    researchId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => ResearchEntity)
    research: ResearchEntity;
}

export class ResearchEntity{

    @BelongsTo(() => NameEntity)
    primaryName: NameEntity;
}
```

when I query `ResearchRequestEntity` I want to bring `research` with its `primaryName`.

how can I get `research` and `primaryName`.

I have one constraint here, im sending the query/options over http, so I cant do: `model: ResearchEntity`, maybe I can do `{model:'ResearchEntity'}` but this will return an error:
`include.model.getTableName is not a function`.

Please suggest a "dynamic" way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
include: [{association:'research', include:['primaryName']}]
```